# css shows up even if I dont have anything in css file?

Tags: python, css, flask

Its weird but I removed everything in the css file, the website still shows all the colours and stuff. I dont know what happened so I need t ask for help.

here is the main html:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-dropdownhover.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='style.css') }}">
</head>
```

the style sheet:

(yes its literally nothing)
I'm running flask and I dont know whats happening so..
also the screenshot for the webiste when I put all the styles in:
[image]

would be happy if anyone can help me get past this part

Comment: Hard refresh using `Ctrl+F5`

Comment: @StukedCoder I did that and all the styles are lost, but just now I added the styles back in and did the ctrl f5 again it didnt show any styles

Comment: nevermind I figured it out, it was weird tho I thought flask debugger would change it

Answer (score 0):

Likely, your browser is caching the CSS. If you are in Google Chrome, a longer-term solution while developing is to open the DevTools (Ctrl+Shft+I), go to Network/Disable Cache and then hit the "open to new window" button so you can minimise it.